# Adding some security to beacons in ionic app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ibeacon, ionic-native

Hello I’m using  https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon ( ionic native ibeacon) library to detect ibeacons with no problem.But I have concerns about cloning an ibeacon with a smartphone and transmit as an ibeacon with same uuid,minor,major values.It seems so easy with beacon locater apps in the market.
How can I understand this situation with cordova plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything Cordova-specific about this issue, it is a limitation of Bluetooth beacons that transmit an unencrypted identifier.  Three options:

1. Accept that for most all use cases, there is no major incentive to spoof a beacon, and it is exceedingly rare that people do this except for demonstration purposes.  This is what the vast majority of real world implementations do.
2. Rotate the identifier of your beacons periodically to reduce the time window that they can be spoofed.  This is a tedious process unless you automate it with a configuration app (specific to your beacon manufacturer.)
3. Use an encrypted beacon format like Eddystone-EID or Gimbal.  These formats require you to register your beacon with a server owned by Google or Gimbal, respectively, then make a server call to convert the secure hash identifier transmitted by the beacon to an identifier that makes sense to you.  This is effectively an automated and secured rotation mechanism like in option 2.